# Can I add a callback function or statement after a $timeout in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function fadeAlertMessage() {
   $scope.alertMessagePopUp = true;
   $timeout(function() {
      $scope.fade = true;
   }, 5000)  function() { 
   $scope.alertMessagePopUp = false;
}
```

I have a problem here and I hope someone can help me go through this, but first is it possible to do this? I have an alert message which pops up when I create something in my list and then I want to fade it out, but after fading it out it leaves a white space in my User Interface, so I need some solution on this.   I tried to turn the Alert message off, but seems the code above doesn't work. Is it Possible though? The fading is already functioning so the real problem here is turning of the alert message.

The question is does angular  have callbacks?

Comment: sorry i type the question 3 times pls do understand thank you :)

Comment: You can correct your own typos in the question by using the [edit] button provided. You do not need others to do the edits for you!

Answer (score 0):

If your are using [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) you can add lifecycle hooks. See the "[Callbacks and Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#callbacks-and-promises)" section.